# @types/draft-js type definitions overshadows immutable-js's type definitions

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

1. in typescript project (e.g. `yarn create react-app --typescript x`)
2. install `draft-js`, `@types/draft-js`, `immutable`
3. try `import { hash } from "immutable";`

Result: `Module '"immutable"' has no exported member 'hash'.ts(2305)` error (in vscode as well as in build logs)
even though

`grep "export function hash" node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.d.ts`
reveals

`export function hash(value: any): number;`

Because it uses type definitions in

`node_modules/@types/draft-js/node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.d.ts`
instead of

`node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.d.ts`

I'm not even sure where to open an issue about this because it seems to be universal for the entirety javascript and front-end development domains.

What do I do

please help